# how to make fancybox not recharge the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I automatically load content with fancybox but every time I click reload content and i need the user select data in selectbox.

FANCYBOX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#yt").fancybox(
        {
            closeBtn : false,
            closeClick  : false, fancybox 
  openEffect  : 'none',
  closeEffect : 'none',
  helpers   : { 
   overlay : {closeClick: false}  
  }
        }
    ).trigger('click');
    });
</script>
```

This is the HTML CODE

```
<form name="form1" action="">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>Number</div>
                <select id="number" name="number">
                    <option value="01">01</option>
                    <option value="02">02</option>
                    <option value="03">03</option>
                    <option value="04">04</option>
                    <option value="05">05</option>
                    <option value="06">06</option> 
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.fancybox(
        {
            closeBtn : false,
            href: "#yt",
            closeClick  : false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox 
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers   : { 
               overlay : {closeClick: false} // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox 
              }
        }
    ).trigger('click');
    });
```